# WebService com interface de contrato genérica

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou tentando hospedar um Web Service em um serviço do Windows. E ao configurar o `serviceModel` no `App.config` estou recebendo o seguinte aviso de erro do editor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O WebService está um projeto do tipo `Biblioteca de Serviço do WCF` e o projeto que hospedará o WebService é do tipo `Windows Service`.
Abaixo segue o código da interface de contrato:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace FoxMovieStoreWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataPersistance<in T> where T : new ( )
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Insert ( T value );

        [OperationContract]
        bool Change ( T value );

        [OperationContract]
        bool Delete ( T value );

        // TODO: Adicione suas operações de serviço aqui
    }

    // Use um contrato de dados como ilustrado no exemplo abaixo para adicionar tipos compostos a operações de serviço.
    // Você pode adicionar arquivos XSD ao projeto. Depois de criar o projeto, use os tipos de dados definidos nele diretamente, com o namespace "FoxMovieStoreWebService.ContractType".

}
```

Aqui o `App.config` Windows Service onde eu faço a configuração do WebService:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudAddress" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudBooking" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudCashDesk" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudClient" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.Dependent" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudDevolution" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudFunctionary" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudGame" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudMovCashDesk" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudMovie" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

        <service name="FoxMovieStoreWebService.CrudRent" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9876"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FoxMovieStoreWebService.IDataPersistance"/>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceConfig">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Tenho quase certeza que esse erro é pelo fato de eu ter criado a interface de contrato como uma Interface Genérica, pois não sei como fica no `App.config` nesse caso. Caso minha suspeita se confirme mudarei o título da pergunta.

Comment: Não funciona esse tipo de implementação realmente pelo tipo genérico...

Comment: O que exatamente você diz que não funciona? Apenas pelo fato da interface ser genérica?
Fiz um teste aqui, criei um [projeto](http://pastebin.com/yNnm2GqY) console e dessa vez deixei as configurações não mais no `App.config` mas fiz de forma imperativa, ou seja, realizei as configurações via código C#. Não recebi nenhum erro de compilação.

Comment: Bom tente executar operações de gravação alteração e tente também disponibilizar para terceiros dessa forma...

Comment: Complementado do que o @VirgilioNovic comentou, talvez não funcione assim, com uma interface "tão genérica". Lembre-se que um contrato é uma forma de, o cliente e o servidor do serviço definirem **o mais claramente possível** as regras, ou seja, o que o serviço irá receber o que vai devolver. Essa sua interface não respeita bem esse conceito de contrato, seria o equivalente a dizer *"me manda qualquer coisa ai que eu insiro, altero, etc"*, entende? Isso pode funcionar bem em uma classe, mas mas não em um contrato de serviço.